# Neo4J Jaccard Similarity encounters a ClassCastException

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was attempting to calculate the similarity between two articles, but as I attempted to emulate the cuisine sample code seen here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/similarity-jaccard/

I encountered a class cast exception.

An representation of my data is as follows:
A representation of my test data csv files is as follows: CSV used to create all title nodes:

```
title_id,title  
T1,Article Title 1  
T2,Article Title 2
```

CSV that I want to use to create the relationships:

```
title_id,keyword_id,keyword  
T1,K1,aaa  
T1,K2,bbb  
T1,K3,ccc  
T1,K4,ddd  
T2,K1,aaa  
T2,K5,eee  
T2,K6,fff  
T2,K4,ddd
```

The code I used is as follows:

```
MATCH (search_query:Title)
      -[:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(k_id:Keyword)
     <-[:HAS_KEYWORDS]-(return_query:Title)
      -[r2:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(rec_k:Keyword)
WITH {kw:id(search_query), categories: collect(k_id)} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data, {similarityCutoff: 0.0})
YIELD item1, item2, count1, count2, intersection, similarity

RETURN algo.getNodeById(item1).name AS from, 
       algo.getNodeById(item2).name AS to,
       intersection, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

I end up getting this error message:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure
`algo.similarity.jaccard.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I'm not quite sure where I went wrong, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the correct parameter names (`item` instead `kw`) in the options for the procedure, and the correct data types (`id` instead `node`):

```
WITH {kw:id(search_query), categories: collect(k_id)} as userData
```

=>

```
WITH {items:id(search_query), categories: collect(id(k_id))} as userData
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried that and now it says it failed to invoke the procedure due to a Null pointer exception..  

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.similarity.jaccard.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ah, I see now! I misunderstood (and misread) previously. It works!!!

Thank you so much!!!